# Ionic radio group on new page component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic and angular and I want to create a custom element directive, like:

```
<radio-group 
    value="'a'" 
    values="{{['a', 'b', 'c']}}" 
    on-value-change="onChange()" 
    radio-group-name="'Values'"
></radio-group>

function onChange(newValue){}
```

so it's pretty similar to [example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRadio/) on ionic site, but I need it to generate link

```
<a href="#/radio-group-page">Values</a>
```

by clicking it we are going on a new page with values list and 'Values' title. When we select new item, `on-value-change` event fires.

Is it possible? I don't know how to bind this functionality between pages.

I dont want to create new template and controller for each radio-group.

Comment: you want dynamic radio button list. So if it clicks on section 1 >> it displays radio-button based on section 1?

Comment: @Smit, what do you mean by section 1?

Comment: I click on link on page 1, then go to page 2. On page 2 there is a list of radio buttons (a, b, c). When I click on another item and press 'done' `on-value-change` event fires on page 1.

Comment: `section 1` is just a header name. I gave a sample in order to understand your question correctly

Comment: have added answer please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me for a newbie best would be to set a factory!

```
myApp.factory('Data', function(){
        var data =
            {
                valueSelected: ''
            };

        return {
            getValue: function () {
                return data.valueSelected;
            },
            setValue: function (selected) {
                data.valueSelected = selected;
            }
        };
    });
```

In your radio controller:

```
myApp.controller('RadioCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    Data.setValue($scope.radioValue);
});
```

In your main Controller

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    var valueReceived = Data.getValue();
    //do what you want with your data!
});
```